# Doctrine dql orderby with expression

Tags: doctrine, dql

How can i do something like this in doctrine2 dql

```
Select  m* from Members
WHERE MemberID = "6" or MemberId="3" or MemberID="5"
ORDER BY MemberID = "6" DESC, MemberId="3" DESC, MemberID="5" DESC;
```

Comment: Excuse-me, but what is the expected reult of this query?

Comment: To first ordet by member id 6 then by,3, then by 5 respectively